# How to use Entity Framework code-first to generate a clustered primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Here is what we have in sql statement, some field names are omitted to save some space:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payment](
   [PaymentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   [ItemId] [int] NULL,
   ...
CONSTRAINT [PK_Payment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [PaymentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I probably cannot just say,

```
HasKey(p => p.PaymentId)
```

What is the correct way to generate this complicated `CONSTRAINT` clause in Entity Framework Code First?

Comment: Why can't use you `HasKey()`?

Comment: Sorry, i mean `HasKey()` won't be able to generate this `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`. There must be some other specification code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot duplicate your issue.  When I use the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Adjustment>()
    .HasKey(a => a.Id)
```

The sql generated looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Adjustment](
  [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  // additional unrelated fields removed
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Adjustment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
   [Id] ASC
 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Do you mean there is nothing else we need?

Comment: Need for what?  using `HasKey()` or the `KeyAttribute()` both cause EF to generate the PK for the table on the specified column/property.

Comment: Then, is it possible to generate a nonclustered primary key?

Comment: I don't know, but asking that question makes me wonder; there are so few situations when that is necessary, is your situation really one?

Comment: In many situations, we don't want to index on the guid column. It will be better (performance) to index on another unique text field, like ssn or driver's license on people.

Comment: Both of those are not unique.  But beyond that I don't know how to tell EF to do what you want (it has many limitations). Are you using SQL Server?